# how to initiate angular project with standalone component

Tags: angular, components

now that angular has released standalone components, can I initiate angular with only standalone component and remove `NgModule` all-together?

Comment: I assume your question refers to building new angular projects with the cli like so ng new myapp --standalone

Comment: I found it's not in the cli yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can using the new introduced `bootstrapApplication` which is imported from `@angular/platform-browser` in the `main.ts` file

here is the full code

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```